# Get latest updates from a collection of database entries (Mongodb, Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, feed

I am trying to create a newsfeed and I am trying to conjure up the best way (or algorithm in a sense) to get a bunch of Objects a user is subscribed to in with mongoose and then return the latest updates ordered chronologically from all those objects:

ie. with mongoose schemas:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    subscribed: [ObjectSchema]
  });

var ObjectSchema = new Schema({
    updates: [UpdateSchema]
});

var UpdateSchema = new Schema({
    date_updated: Date,
    message: String
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer. You just have to find all the updates sorted by the date_updated property.

Maybe I didn't understood your question but as asked, you just have to do that.
Tell me if you wanted something else.

Comment: Well the user has multiple Objects, which have multiple events. So I'm wondering what would be the most efficient algorithm to loop through the objects get the latest events and then sort them by date_updated. Or better yet if there is a particular mongodb or Mongoose command for this?

Comment: Mmmh I don't know the schema of your collections because Mongoose generate it. Can you show it ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by this, could you clarify?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you need to get it with the most efficient algorithm, you have to use the mongodb native client with NodeJS, not an ORM like Mongoose. And after that, to get the most efficient algorithm, it depends more on MongoDB than NodeJS. So the best option for you, is to ask MongoDB users, not NodeJS developers.